# Perl cross compilation issue

Tags: perl

I am newbie to perl cross compilation.
I'm trying to install perl from source as given in www.perl.org.
Commands followed are ./Configure, Make, Make test.

To find the path for specific installation, the CLI "perl -V" shows error as follows.

```
# ./perl -V
Can't locate Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.9 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

I think i have done some mistake in path inclusions.
Please let me know the reason and solution for successfull cross compilation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really trying to install Perl 5.9? That's a very old development branch. You should be using Perl 5.14.

Comment: Are you really doing *cross* compilation (i.e., compiling the Perl sources on one platform for use on another platform)?  If so (or if not), what platform(s) are you using?

Comment: @Quentin I'm trying to install 5.10.0. Not sure why it is 5.9 in the path. My machine consists of old version of NetBSD operating system. I am not very sure which Perl suits it. So going with Perl 5.10.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, host machine is Linux and the target is NetBSD.

Comment: Why not just compile it on NetBSD?  Or you can probably [install a binary package](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/lang/perl5/README.html).  Note that Perl 5.10 is still pretty old; it was released four years ago.  Do you have a specific reason not to install a newer Perl?

Comment: Previously on p5p: http://markmail.org/thread/cfh6jkr2i4osu6k2 http://markmail.org/thread/sjcxknzuxaxqv7fr

Comment: @KeithThompson I tried to install Perl directly on target BSD machine. Make was succeeded but "Make test" failed for 2 tests. Failed 2 tests out of 1388, 99.86% okay. ../ext/DynaLoader/t/DynaLoader.t ../ext/POSI/t/sysconf.t                                                          Also prompts for setting dynamic library path search path LD_LIBRARY_PATH. May i know how/where should i set the path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably possible to cross-compile Perl (building on Linux and targeting for BSD), but there's not much point in doing so.  NetBSD is as capable as Linux of building Perl locally, and that's almost certainly what you should do.

You can build it from source, following the installation instructions, or better yet you can [install a binary package](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/lang/perl5/README.html), since somebody else has already done the work of building Perl from source for you.

Unless you have a very specific requirement for an old version, you should install the most recent production version, which I believe is 5.14.2.

You mentioned in a comment that when you build Perl from source on your target BSD machine, `Make test` had 2 failures.  You had a 99.86% success rate.  Surely that's good enough -- and you're not likely to do any better by cross-compiling.  You might want to look into those failures and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` issue (I don't know what it should be set to for NetBSD), but those issues aren't so serious that you should give up and use a radically different approach.